# Ошибка при возврате значения, public - функции класса

Tags: c++builder

Здравствуйте.

---

Вот описание класса. (Хранит ФИО и Возраст)

```
class Military
{ private: AnsiString FIO; int Age;
public:
Military(AnsiString FIOName, int MA):FIO(FIOName),Age(MA){};
Military(){};
~Military(){};
int get_Age(){return Age;};
void set_Age(int MA){Age=MA;};
```

Я создаю класс `Military М1;`
устанавливаю возраст `M1.set_Age(int MA)` в форме **Form1**
Однако при попытке вызова `ShowMessage(M1.get _Age());` (получение значения MA) в форме **Form2** происходит вывод нуля, т.е. значение переменной **Age** класса **Military** обнуляется, хотя при вызове `ShowMessage(M1.get _Age());` в форме **Form1** выводится именно то значение которое я присвоил MA и указал в `M1.set_Age(int MA)`.

---

Вопрос, как исправить эту ошибку ,чтобы была возможность получения значений класса в запросе из любой формы?

Comment: у Вас видимо разные объекты у двух форм.

Comment: Ну на Form1 есть поле Edit1, M1.set_Age(StrToInt(Edit1->Text));
а на 2ой просто при нажатии на Button1 выполняется ShowMessage(M1.get _Age());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно закрывать, я объявил сами непосредственно классы в хеадере с их описанием, а в остальные формы их не включил, **extern**'ом)